# OpenCV throws a bad argument error when using addWeighted()

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, overlay

I am trying to add an overlay on top of an image using `cv2.addWeighted(...)` but it throws the following error:

```
dst = cv2.addWeighted(logo, alpha, overlay, 1-alpha, 0)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) /tmp/pip-req-build-99ib2vsi/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:691: error: (-5:Bad argument) When the input arrays in add/subtract/multiply/divide functions have different types, the output array type must be explicitly specified in function 'arithm_op'
```

This error doesn't make sense to me because I checked the docs and my arguments were appropriate.  This is my code.

```
def overlay(path):
    logo = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    alpha = logo[:, :, 3]

    overlay = np.zeros(logo.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    overlay[:, :, 2] = alpha
    overlay[:, :, 3] = alpha

    alpha = 0.5

    dst = cv2.addWeighted(logo, alpha, overlay, 1-alpha, 0)

    pil_image = Image.fromarray(dst).convert('RGBA')

    return pil_image
```

**Update**

So the overlay works now but there are some issues.  I made the following change to my code:

```
dst = cv2.addWeighted(logo, alpha, overlay, 1 - alpha, 0, dtype=cv2.CV_32F).astype(np.uint8)
```

This is what happens when I change the color on the overlay.

[image]

New full code:

```
def overlay(path):
    logo = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    alpha = logo[:, :, 3]

    overlay = np.zeros(logo.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    overlay[:, :, 2] = alpha
    r = 0
    g = 255
    b = 0
    overlay[:, :, :3] = r, g, b
    # overlay[:, :, 3] = alpha

    alpha = 0.5

    dst = cv2.addWeighted(logo, alpha, overlay, 1 - alpha, 0, dtype=cv2.CV_32F).astype(np.uint8)

    pil_image = Image.fromarray(dst).convert('RGBA')
```

Comment: It is not clear about checker board.

Comment: @Hihikomori That's fair but can you tell me how I can experiment with different colors?

Comment: Check my answer, i updated it.

Comment: @Hihikomori It has the same checkerboard error. I managed to get a picture of it. Check the edit to see it and my new full code...

Comment: Add: overlay[:, :, 3] = 255, The checker boarf is because alpha channel is 0.

Comment: Where exactly? And why am I setting it back to red?

Comment: Forget it I updated the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dst = cv2.addWeighted(logo, alpha, overlay, 1-alpha, 0, dtype=cv2.CV_32F).astype(np.uint8)
```

Set color to overlay:

```
r = 10
g = 190
b = 100
a = 255
overlay[:, :] = r,g,b,a
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 4), <u2

Answer (score 0):

The logo and the the overlay objects have a different dtype causing a parsing error. To fix this, you must specify the dtype of the output in the addWeighted command. Here is an example with a type 32 output:

```
dst = cv2.addWeighted(logo, alpha, overlay, 1-alpha, 0, dtype=cv2.CV_32F).astype(np.uint8)
```

Sources / Additional References: 
https://github.com/Prasad9/ImageAugmentationTypes/issues/2

Comment: This code throws an error with my PIL conversion that follows `dst`

Comment: Convert dst to uint8.

Answer (score 0):

```
F1=np.round(im1*0.3,0)
F2=np.round(im2*0.7,0)
F3=F1+F2
img=np.uint8(F3)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```